# Configure a Guest network on a Sonicwall TZ-205 N

Tags: wireless, router, sonicwall

I'm trying to configure a Sonicwall TZ-205 N to have 2 wireless networks. The first wireless network is a guest network which only has access to the internet (client isolation would be nice but is not a requirement). The second wireless network is a hidden network that has access to the internet as well as other devices on the LAN.

Can this all be accomplished with a single device or will I need to purchase a second sonicwall wireless device?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

One option with the sonicwall enhanced os for the TZ-205 would be setting up wireless guest services (http://www.sonicwall.com/us/en/support/2213.html?fuzeurl=http://www.fuzeqna.com/sonicwallkb/ext/kbdetail.aspx?kbid=4955).

Otherwise I think you may be able to setup new wireless profile and virtual access point. Then manually prevent access from it to your LAN zone with firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

One single device (Sonicpoint) is enough for the configuration you're seeking. If you need 2 wireless networks you'll have to create 2 virtual interfaces (and 2 different zones).
Client isolation is also possible.